# Receiving ITMS-90189: "Redundant Binary Upload. You've already uploaded a build with build number 2.0 for version 1.0."

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload build 2.0 for version 1.0, but keep getting the build error:

ITMS-90189 "Redundant Binary Upload. You've already uploaded a build with build number 2.0 for version 1.0."

My previous builds 1.0 - 1.9 uploaded just fine.

When 1.0(2.0) failed, I tried jumping to 1.0(2.1), then version 1.1.0(2.0) and even tried jumping to version 2.0(2.0) but that didn't seem to help.
I made sure to update the AppStore Connect version as well when jumping to 1.1.0 and 2.0.

I've checked my info.plist and the "Bundle versions string, short" and "bundle version" values match the version and build number from the Project/Targets/General tab.

Finally I've cleaned and restarted Xcode to no avail and I'm out of ideas. Hoping some can help or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of App Store Connect > App > Activity > All Builds?

Comment: @Max I assumed the builds hadn't gone through due to the error message and submission rejection, but I see them in AppStore Connect after all. I guess I'm stuck on Version 2.0.0 now, but at least it's working. Thanks